# How to copy a value between fields within each object in an embedded array of objects in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

In my 'assemblies' collection, each document contains an embedded array of objects called 'partlist':

```
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("0001"),
 "pn" : "01",
 "title" : "MyAssembly",
 "partlist" : [ 
 {
    "id" : "",
    "pn" : "1234",
    "desc" : "myPart1",
 }, 
 {
    "id" : "",
    "pn" : "5678",
    "desc" : "myPart2",
 }]
}
```

Within each object, I need to copy the value from 'partlist.pn' into 'partlist.id'. I used:

```
db.assemblies.aggregate([{$set:{"partlist.id":"$partlist.pn"}}])
```

hoping to achieve this:

```
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("0001"),
 "pn" : "01",
 "title" : "MyAssembly",
 "partlist" : [ 
 {
    "id" : "1234",
    "pn" : "1234",
    "desc" : "myPart1",
 }, 
 {
    "id" : "5678",
    "pn" : "5678",
    "desc" : "myPart2",
 }]
}
```

Instead it returned to 'id' an array of ALL the 'pn' values in 'partlist':

```
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("0001"),
 "pn" : "01",
 "title" : "MyAssembly",
 "partlist" : [ 
 {
    "id" : [ 
        "1234",
        "5678"
     ],
    "pn" : "1234",
    "desc" : "myPart1",
 }, 
 {
    "id" : [ 
        "1234",
        "5678"
     ],
    "pn" : "5678",
    "desc" : "myPart2",
 }]
}
```

What is the correct syntax for copying the one value within each object?

Comment: It `id`, `pn` and `desc` all you have as fields, or are there more fields?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is, you can use `$map` to modify each elements and mearg the `id` with the help of `$mergeObject`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      "partlist": {
        $map: {
          input: "$partlist",
          in: {
            "$mergeObjects": [
              "$$this",
              {
                id: "$$this.pn"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3CwEusEQRh6)**

Comment: Thanks varman, that did the trick. So much to learn and so little time...

Comment: @user1925590 consider to accept the answer which may help others in future

Comment: Sure. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

- If the `pn` does not exist it retrieves initial object.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      partlist: {
        $map: {
          input: "$partlist",
          as: "p",
          in: {
            $cond: [
              "$$p.pn",
              {
                $mergeObjects: [
                  "$$p",
                  {
                    "id": "$$p.pn"
                  }
                ]
              },
              "$$p"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/aQ3gCBZ6Qpa)